# Is there some counterexample that discontinuous positive function which is not bounded below by constant on compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be some topological space ,let $K\subset X$ be some compact subset and $f:X\to \Bbb{R}$ be some map that is positive at each point. We know that if $f$ is continuous then $f|_K \ge C_K >0$  for some constant $C_K$ since continuous map maps compact set to compact set.

The question is :Is there some counterexample of discontinuous function,that not bounded below on compact set?

Comment: $X=\mathbb R, K=[0,1], f(x)=x$ for $0 <x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: thank you $\ \ \ $

Comment: Just for your information, in English we call it a "counter-examples", not a "non-example". A counter-example is an example that is counter to a statement. I.e., it shows the statement to be false, at least for one case.  "Non-example" isn't a phrase one normally hears. I would interpret it as meaning something that just fails to be an example of the statement. It need not contradict it. So $2$ is a counter-example to the statement "all primes are odd", while $4$ would be a non-example.